# How to disable a UITableViewCell but still have interactions with accessory views (i.e UISwitch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way that I can disable a UITableViewCell from triggering the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` delegate, while still retaining the ability to use a UISwitch that is in the accessory view of that cell.

I know you can set cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO, this will disable the cell but is also prevents me from using the switch in the accessory view. I know I could also try to detect what cell was tapped in the `didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` method but since my table view is dynamic and changes depending on what the user is doing that could get messy.

I'm looking for a simple and elegant solution that I could use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

if you do not wan't to use cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO
then you set cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

and let your cell trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Now here in this method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" you have to avoid / ignore selection , by comparing object type from your datasource array at that particular index.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener directly to your `UISwitch` instead of relying on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    // Here I assume you created a subclass MyCell of UITableViewCell
    // And exposed a member named 'switch' that points to your UISwitch

    MyCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[MyCell alloc] init];
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; // This could be moved into MyCell class
         [cell.switch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }

    // Now we need some way to know which cell is associated with the switch
    cell.switch.tag = indexPath.row;
}
```

Now to listen to swich events, add this method in the same class

```
-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch*)switch {
    NSUInteger cellIndex = switch.tag;
    ...
}
```